# InfoPath Form - Email multiple accounts based upon certain field selections

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, infopath-rules

I am trying to build an InfoPath form which contains multiple sections. One of these sections contains a number of RadioButtons asking whether the user specified is a member of certain groups/departments. Depending on whether the user selects "Yes" to these, I need to send out an email containing parts of the form to a particular email address (but only the section which is relevant to that particular question).

In addition I need the entire form to be sent out to a certain email address regardless of what has been filled in.

To give some further clarfication; I have a form divided into Sections 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Section 7 contains a number of RadioButton questions which asks whether user is a member of a particular group. If he/she answers yes to one then an email should be sent out but only containing the data from section 2 for example and nothing else. Of course he/she could select multiple options in this section and this could result in several emails going out to different accounts each only displaying their relevant section. In addition I also need the full details of the form going to one distinct email address each time.

I hope this make sense but I'm happy to explain further if need be. I'm aware that this almost certainly requires the building of one or more WorkFlows in SharePoint Designer but I'm struggling to come up with a "proof of concept" as to how to go about this.

Any assistance or guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: OK, so you've explained the requirements. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Create an email data connection for each of the possible radio button options and another email data connection for the generic email.

Use rules that evaluate the selected options and send emails via the email data connections. One rule per option. If the option is yes, send the email. Put these rules in the button that submits the form.